# ReplacementAll with list elements

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, map

I'm trying to define a function that replaces certain expressions that appear when calculating scattering amplitudes (not important). Basically, I have a function `spab[a_,c_,b_]`, where `a,b` are single elements and `c` is a list with at most two levels. For example, I can write

```
spab[1,{2,3,4},5]; spab[4,{3},9]; spab[5,{{3,4},{7,6},2},1];
```

etc. I have another function `spbb[a_,c_,b_]` with the same type of arguments and a last function  `spa[a_,b_]` with only single element arguments. What I want to do is to substitute `spab[a_,c_,b_]` for the product

```
(*Sum over all i*) spa[a,c[[1,i]]]*spbb[c[[1,i]],c[[2;;]],b].
```

In other words, I want to take the first element of the list `c` and set it as the single element argument for the `spa` and `spbb` functions. If `c[[1]]` is itself a list, then I want to take each element of this sublist, apply the procedure I just described and then sum over these elements. I'll write up some examples of what I want the result to look like:

```
spab[1,{2,3,4},5]->spa[1,2]*spbb[2,{3,4},5];
spab[5,{{3,4},{7,6},2},1]->spa[5,3]*spbb[3,{7,6},2},1] + spa[5,4]*spbb[4,{7,6},2},1]
```

I though I could achieve this with something like:

```
spab[5,{{3,4},{7,6},2},1]/.spab[a_,c_,b_]->Plus[spa[a,#]*spbb[#,c[[2;;]],b]&/@c[[1]]]
```

In my mind, this first creates a list of products `spa[a,c[[1,i]]]*spbb[c[[1,i]],c[[2;;]],b]` by using the *Map* command with the list `c[[1]]` and then sums over al the elements. However, the result is:

```
During evaluation of In[19]:= Part::partd: Part specification c[[1]] is longer than depth of object.

During evaluation of In[19]:= Part::take: Cannot take positions 2 through -1 in c.

During evaluation of In[19]:= Part::pkspec1: The expression spa[a,1] spbb[1,c[[2;;All]],b] cannot be used as a part specification.

During evaluation of In[19]:= Part::pkspec1: The expression spa[5,1] spbb[1,{{7,6},2},1] cannot be used as a part specification.

Out[19]= (spa[5, {{3, 4}, {7, 6}, 2}] spbb[{{3, 4}, {7, 6}, 2}, {{7, 6}, 2}, 1])[[spa[5, 1]spbb[1, {{7, 6}, 2}, 1]]]
```

What do all these error messages mean? Why do I get this weird result, and what is the factor between `[[ ]]` that appears at the very end? If someone culd help me make things clear and fix this, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: The reason that you're getting the errors is that the expression `Plus[spa[a, #]*spbb[#, c[[2 ;;]], b] & /@ c[[1]]]` gets evaluated before being used in the replacement rule. At that moment, c has no value (and so is not a list that Part can work on). That leads to a cascade of follow on errors as the ReplaceAll is attempted with a broken rule.

Comment: For what it's worth, you could use RuleDelayed:  `spab[5, {{3, 4}, {7, 6}, 2}, 1] /. 
 spab[a_, c_, b_] :> Plus[spa[a, #]*spbb[#, c[[2 ;;]], b] & /@ c[[1]]]`

Comment: That indeed seems to get rid of the error, but then it doesn't perform the sum...

Comment: Right. I was showing that RuleDelayed holds the right side of the rule unevaluated. I still think your best bet is just defining DownValues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than try to do replacements, you could just define DownValues (transformation rules):

```
spab[a_Integer, b : {__Integer}, c_Integer] := 
  spa[a, First@b]*spbb[First@b, Rest@b, c];
spab[a_Integer, b : {_List, ___}, c_Integer] := 
  Dot[Thread[spa[a, First@b]], Thread[spbb[First@b, Rest@b, c], List, 1]]
```

I'm making assumptions about the arguments being Integers and so forth, which may need to be changed. If you don't want these transformations to be applied automatically, then define them for a different symbol (e.g. spabTransform) and then use ReplaceAll with spab->spabTransform.

***Update***

I like this better. Fewer assumptions and removes duplicate arithmetic.

```
spab[a_, b : {_List, ___}, c_] := 
  Dot[Thread[spa[a, First@b]], Thread[spbb[First@b, Rest@b, c], List, 1]];
spab[a_, b : {__}, c_] := spab[a, MapAt[List, b, 1], c];
```

Comment: Could you briefly explain what the different commands are doing? Specifically, I would love some clarification on `b : {_List, ___}`  and  `b : {__}`

Comment: `:=` is infix form of SetDelayed, so we're defining some transformation rules that will become DownValues for spab (you can evaluate `DownValues[spab]` to see how Mathematica will now transform spab-headed expressions). These DownValues, by the way, look a lot like what you would try to do with ReplaceAll rules, but since this functionality is already built into Mathematica, using ReplaceAll is kind of re-inventing the wheel here. ...

Comment: The left had side of these expressions is the pattern to match. You're already familiar with Blank (the underscore). There are other versions, specifically BlankSequence and BlankNullSequence. So, this bit `{__}` (using BlankSequence) is a pattern that will match a List that has at least one element. This bit `{_List, ___}` is a pattern that will match a List whose first element is a List and has zero or more elements following it (that's what BlankNullSequence is for). ...

Comment: The colon is just infix for Pattern. So, `b : {__}` is saying, here is a pattern that we'll name b and the pattern will match a list that has at least one element). Similarly, `b : {_List, ___}` is saying, here is a pattern that we'll name b and that will match a list that has a list in first position and zero or more elements following.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very insightful response :). I'll play around with it and see if I can define everything I have to do in this way.

Comment: Is there a way to say: b is a list with only one element? (this element being possibly also a list)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134999/discussion-between-lericr-and-marcosko).